# How to affect other elements on hover in JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: css, javafx

I am working on an app in JavaFX using SceneBuilder, and I want to add an CSS code that will display label when I hover on a button, I tried:

```
.label
{
-fx-text-fill: transparent;
}
.button:hover ~ .label 
{ 
-fx-text-fill: black; 
}
```

All the elements are in the same container.
So my question is how can I affect label using button?

Comment: If the label's not a descendent of the button, you can't do this entirely in JavaFX CSS; you need to use a listener on the button's `hoverProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this purely with JavaFX CSS since the `Label` is not a descendant of the `button.`

You can, however, alter the style of the `Label` by listening to the `hoverProperty` of your `Button` and setting the style for the `Label` appropriately:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Sample layout
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        // Create the Button and Label
        Button button = new Button("Hover Me!");
        Label label = new Label("You hovered like a pro!");

        // Add a listener to the button's hoverProperty. When it is triggered, we can update the
        // styleclass of the label.
        button.hoverProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // If the current state is true, add the button-hovered styleclass
            if (newValue) {
                label.getStyleClass().add("button-hovered");
            } else {
                // Otherwise, we remove that class
                label.getStyleClass().remove("button-hovered");
            }
        });

        // Add the button and label to the layout
        root.getChildren().addAll(button, label);

        // Create the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        // Apply CSS
        scene.getStylesheets().add("css/style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**HOWEVER**, in your case, you may be going about it the wrong way since you just want to keep the `Label` hidden until the user hovers over the `Button`. In that case, it is probably simpler to just bind the `visibleProperty` of the `Label` to your `hoverProperty` of the `Button`. Doing so takes just one line of code instead of using the listener:

```
label.visibleProperty().bind(button.hoverProperty());
```

Of course, you'll want to remove the `.label` selector from your CSS if you go this route, since it will still make the text transparent.